# TC4426 gets hot while operating

Tags: power, mosfet, power-electronics, mosfet-driver

I am working with TC4426s to switch mosfets via to a 10kHz PWM, using this configuration:
[image: schemtica]
I have a total of 4 mosfets and then two drivers, the first driver does not show problems of overheating and works properly (with a duty cycle of +20 and a +30), however, the second becomes "very" hot (about 50°C, with a duty of +60 and a +80).

I just can't understand why they get so hot. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Does the first one also get hot if ran at +60 and +80?

Comment: @rdtsc I just did the switch: the first driver di not become hot and I noticed that the resistor on the gate of the second driver gets pretty hot. Could the mosfet be broken?

Comment: Possibly, I'd remove it and test it out-of-circuit.  Perhaps even build a simple test jig from two current-limited power supplies. One supply, 12V@10mA across D+ and S- to simulate a load.  The other supply, 12V@10mA across G+ and S-.  Increase supply 2 voltage until gate threshold is found (first supply will start conducting current.)  Chances are, the MOSFET S-D are shorted.

Comment: The resistor getting hot seems to be the tell-tale. With Gate-Source capacitance in the nF range and 10kHz frequency the dissipation on the resistor should be negligible. The FET seems to be the culprit. You may also check the signal at the gate - if you have an oscilloscope. Even a V-meter (and comparing with a healthy channel) may confirm a short.